# How do I receive byte array sent from a server and read 4 single bytes at a time

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedinputstream

I need to receive 320 bytes of data from a server which consist of 80 4 byte int fields. How do I receive them in bytes of 4 and display their respective int values? Thanks.

Not sure if this is right for the receiving part:

```
//for reading the data from the socket 

BufferedInputStream bufferinput=new BufferedInputStream(NewSocket.getInputStream());

DataInputStream datainput=new DataInputStream(bufferinput);

byte[] handsize=new byte[32];

// The control will halt at the below statement till all the 32 bytes are not read from the socket.  

datainput.readFully(handsize);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the buffer be 320 bytes instead of 32.  If you have your own buffer, you can drop the BufferedInputStream. If you use readInt() as suggested, keep the BufferedInputStream.

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
    System.out.println(datainput.readInt());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers and sry for the mistake, it should be 320. Actually I realise there is some float and some other datatypes too within the 320 bytes of data. Can I just do this to display the respective fields in int as well as Float type: <br>

for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) { System.out.println(datainput.readInt()); System.out.println(datainput.readFloat()); } Thanks!

Comment: Not quite. Since you're reading 8 bytes of data now (int + float), you'll to change the for loop to loop 40 times instead of 80.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help so far, I have another question, what if I need to change certain field values to the data read and repack them back into the 320 byte array and lastly send it over to another machine. Not sure how to do it but I was thinking of storing all the data read into individual variables first, make the necessary changes to these variables and repack them in same order as I receive and lastly send it.

Comment: Just write them individually to the stream; they will be in order. Use the DataOutputStream class.